# Script to open customized terminal session

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

I'm not sure if the title got across what I want to do, but here it is:

I am working on a python project that involves a lot of classes. I use Terminal Vim to do my editing.

As you can Imagine, it is a pain to have to open 10 different terminal tabs, title them and open the correct file in them all manually.

I would like to create a script that uses vim to open up all files in a directory in different tabs within the same window. I would like the script to title the tabs as the name of the file it is opening.

I use the gnome-terminal.

Logically I know how I could do it but I just can't seem to find the commands I need.

It seems like I will be able to do what I wan't with the gnome-terminal command, but I can't seem to get it to work right.

**EDIT:** vim -p * is helpful, but I would like to find a solution that does exactly what I outlined above. Having each file in its own TERMINAL tab would allow me to Open/Close/temporarily suspend them individually and would generally allow for more convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around for a bit i was able to do what I wanted with a simple perl script:

I was hung up before because I couldnt get a tab to open in the same window. I now realize that the command is built to create a new instance of a  terminal window.

So:

```
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=def
```

won't open a new tab like I wanted, but will open a new window (def is the name of my profile)

BUT:

```
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=def --tab-with-profile=def
```

WILL open 2 tabs in one window(just not my current window, which is fine)

I can give them a title and execute commands to:

```
gnome-terminal  --tab-with-profile=def --title="foo" -e "vim foobar.txt"
```

opens a new window(single tab), opens foobar.txt in vim and titles the tab for me

With this in mind, I was able to write the following program:

workTime.txt:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;


my $wd = '/home/luke/Pokemon-Battle-Simulator';
chdir($wd);

opendir(DIR,$wd);
my @files = readdir(DIR);

my $cmd = 'gnome-terminal';
my $tab = ' --tab-with-profile=def';
for my $file(@files)
{
    if (($file  ne ".") and ($file ne ".."))
    {
        my $title = '--title=' . $file;
        my $e = "-e 'vim " . $file . "'";
        $cmd .= join(' ', $tab, $title, $e); 
    }
}
print $cmd;

`$cmd`
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly what you want is the -p option. vim -p * will open all the files in the current directory in their own tabs in the same window.

Comment: Just blew my mind.

Comment: Happy to help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the 'screen' unix tool.  It's a terminal "multiplexer" that opens multiple terminals over a single connection (ssh, telnet, or local).  It's configurable to automatically open multiple shells or commands (eg. vim, top, etc) in different screens with a new connection.  It can also preserve sessions across disconnects, so if you are in the middle of editing a document and your ISP drops out for a few minutes, you can go right back to the edits.

ssh + screen + emacs = win!